# Prestashop can't connect to database "An error ocurred:" while trying to test connection

Tags: php, prestashop-1.7

this is happening to me while installing PrestaShop 1.7 on my localhost using PHP 8 and xamp 3.2.4. I have tried creating an user and password to access my db also differents db names and still gives me this error. I tried even installing and old version of PrestaShop (1.6) and still the same.

Cant find much info about this on the web. Seems to be a new error but if everyone has some insight I take it.

Cheers

[image: This happens when I test connection to DB]

Comment: Prestashop doesn't work with PHP 8 - This could be the problem - See requirements here => https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/basics/installation/system-requirements/

Comment: Yes, I had verify all of that. Uncommeneted all the extensions needed, which the installation guided me through. But its just at the moment I test the connection to my server/db. All my server parameters I checked and even tried creating an user and password for to test and had the same error when testing my connection to my server/db

Comment: I just had a second look around. And it just seems that prestashop is not compatible with PHP 8 at all. Thanks for you help anyways

Answer (score 2):

Prestoshop is still not compatible with php 8 wich the latest xampp version have so you need to install older version or at least install php 7.4 side by side with php 8.
Here the official supported php version page: https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/basics/installation/system-requirements/#php-compatibility-chart

Answer (score 0):

First time i instaled the latest version of xampp and I had the same problem with prestashop database connection error .Second time i instaled an older version of XAMPP and it worked.